# Linux take out string from file and use it as file name?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I am writing script and stuck at some point.

**File 1:** this line is in other file

```
#!/bin/sh

sh ~/.test/Folder-Name/.filetest &
```

**File 2:** In this file, I want to grep the location of *~/.test/Folder-Name/.filetest* this file.
It includes hyphens, dots, slashed. I tried it with sed and grep with many regular expressions but unfortunately it doesn't work for me.
for example

```
SelectedFile=`cat Anotherfile.txt | grep -Rril '~\/\.conky\/[A-Z-a-z]\/\.conkyrc' > ~/abc`
```

Comment: What do you want the result of processing file 1 to look like? You haven't made that clear.

Comment: Really not clear what you're trying to do here....

Comment: The string `~/.test/Folder-Name/.filetest` doesn't match the regex `~/\.conky/[A-Za-z]/\.conkyrc`, so that's definitely not going to match. I assume that's not the pattern you're really grepping for, but you haven't given us enough information to guess at what the problem might be.

Comment: Actually from first file I want to grep this string ~/.test/Folder-Name/.filetest .
While executing 2nd file, how to do it in second file.

Comment: Please! Could you guys help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is not quite complete:

```
'~\/\.conky\/[A-Z-a-z]\/\.conkyrc'
             ^^^^^^^^^
```

In the marked location, you are asking for a single character. What you want is many of that character:

```
'~\/\.conky\/[A-Z-a-z]*\/\.conkyrc'
                      ^
```

There is a `*` added!

---

Note also that you don't need to escape the `/`s:

```
'~/\.conky/[A-Z-a-z]*/\.conkyrc'
```

Furthermore, depending on the possible patterns, you may also get away with matching any non-whitespace character instead of just `A-Z-a-z`:

```
'~/\.conky/[^ ]*/\.conkyrc'
```

---

Note that you are invoking `grep` in a very redundant and incorrect way. First of all, instead of:

```
cat X | grep Y
```

you can simply do:

```
grep Y X
```

second, some of the options you are giving to grep are unnecessary or wrong. For example `-R` (and the redundant `-r`) mean recursive search. But you are not searching a directory!! Second `-i` says the search is case insensitive, which is probably redundant since the pattern already has the correct cases. Third, you are giving it `-l` which means "give the file that has the pattern", not "the line that matched the pattern".

Regarding the later, you may actually want the file name, it's ok, but then for sure you shouldn't pipe the file in `grep`, but give it the name directly so it can know it!

So in short, try this:

```
grep -l '~/\.conky/[^ ]*/\.conkyrc' AnotherFile.txt
```

If you want to write this to another file, add a redirection:

```
grep ... > some_file
```

But if you want to keep the output in a variable, *don't* redirect it, otherwise you'll lose it! So:

```
SelectedFile=$(grep -l '~/\.conky/[^ ]*/\.conkyrc' AnotherFile.txt)
```

By the way, if you intend to search for the file (not knowing that it's in `AnotherFile.txt`, since otherwise the search is rather silly), you can do recursive search on a directory:

```
grep -rl '~/\.conky/[^ ]*/\.conkyrc' SomeDirectory > ~/abc
```

Comment: After using last 4th `'~/\.conky/[^ ]*/\.conkyrc'` expression. I have got this output in ~/abc file 
`(standard input)`

Comment: That's because you are giving `grep` the option `-l` which says: _show the file that matches the pattern_. You are giving the file content in a pipe, so of course it tells you that the pattern got matched in the standard input.

Comment: Then how to send this `~/.test/Folder-Name/.filetest` file location to `~/abc` file. Thanks

Comment: ok, it is write complete line with `grep -i '~/\.conky/[^ ]*/\.conkyrc' > ~/abc`
But I want only file location. Thanks

Comment: If you read carefully, I had used `-l` not `-i`.

Comment: Yes but `-l` only write `(standard input)` to `~/abc` file, not location.
I used this line `SelectedFile=$(grep -l '~/\.conky/[^ ]*/\.conkyrc' AnotherFile.txt)` but it prints everything in `~/abc` in file from `Anotherfile.txt`
I want to write only `~/.test/Folder-Name/.filetest` location in `~/abc` file.

Thanks for help

Comment: @ubuntuuser, please read what I wrote carefully. You can never know the file name if you are piping it in `grep`. For that, stop using pipe and give the file directly to `grep`.